# Get an SQL string from a Zend\Db\Sql\Select object in a test

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I have a class that returns a `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` object.

Inside the test with phpunit I try to get the sql string via

```
var_dump($select->getSqlString());
```

But I get an error message:

```
Attempting to quote a value without specific driver level 
support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a 
production environment.
```

Inside my bootstrap for phpunit I define

```
putenv('APP_ENV=test');
```

I also tried

```
var_dump($select->getSqlString(new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql()));
```

but get a similar error

```
Attempting to quote a value in Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql
without extension/driver support can introduce security
vulnerabilities in a production environment.
```

What can I do to get the string in my test without a database adapter/driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ([
 'driver'         => 'Pdo',
 'dsn'            => 'sqlite:./test.sql',
]);

$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->orPredicate (new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('table.cat1', 1))
->orPredicate (new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat2', 2));

$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql ($adapter);
$select = $sql->select ();
$select->from ('table')->where ($where);
echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject ($select);
```

Comment: Works, thanks! I added namespaces for Adapter and Sql in your post.

Answer (score 1):

@acond
Since

```
$sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject ($select)
```

is deprecated, better use

```
$sql->buildSqlString($select)
```